# PostgreSQL service frozen and can't restart properly

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 and PostgreSQL 9.3.

Server is still for testing so I'm alone and only have a .net application doing consult with `npgsql` to the db, mostly doing some stored procedures and some update with `NpgsqlDataAdapter`.

In pgAdmin sometimes I'm doing a simple query and then take forever like PostgreSQL is frozen.

I go to service stop the `postgresql` service, but in the task manager still appear some "postgres.exe" process.

I can't restart PostgreSQL service until I kill those orphan process one by one by hand.

So what can cause the `postgresql` service frozen?

Why are those orphan process still living after I stop the service?

[image: a busy cat]

#### Log file

The stored procedure is moving data from a db to another using `dblink`. And fail doing the `DROP TABLE` before recreate the table. There is also 2 other thread working with the db and those are still running without trouble.

```
2014-07-08 11:42:10 VET LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2014-07-08 11:36:44 VET  
2014-07-08 11:42:10 VET FATAL:  the database system is starting up  
2014-07-08 11:42:10 VET LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress  
2014-07-08 11:42:10 VET FATAL:  the database system is starting up  
2014-07-08 11:42:10 VET LOG:  redo starts at A9/47827B0  
2014-07-08 11:42:14 VET FATAL:  the database system is starting up  
2014-07-08 11:42:15 VET LOG:  record with zero length at A9/5683970  
2014-07-08 11:42:15 VET LOG:  redo done at A9/5683930  
2014-07-08 11:42:15 VET LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2014-07-08 11:39:23.99-04:30  
2014-07-08 11:42:16 VET FATAL:  the database system is starting up    
2014-07-08 11:42:17 VET LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections  
2014-07-08 11:42:17 VET LOG:  autovacuum launcher started  
2014-07-08 12:27:35 VET ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request  
2014-07-08 12:27:35 VET CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP TABLE if exists app.vzla_traffic"     PL/pgSQL function app."LoadTraffic"() line 7 at SQL statement  
2014-07-08 12:27:35 VET STATEMENT:  select app."LoadTraffic"()  
2014-07-08 12:32:32 VET ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request  
2014-07-08 12:32:32 VET CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP TABLE if exists app.vzla_traffic"     PL/pgSQL function app."LoadTraffic"() line 7 at SQL statement  
2014-07-08 12:32:32 VET STATEMENT:  select app."LoadTraffic"()  
2014-07-08 12:37:30 VET ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request  
2014-07-08 12:37:30 VET CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP TABLE if exists app.vzla_traffic"     PL/pgSQL function app."LoadTraffic"() line 7 at SQL statement  
2014-07-08 12:37:30 VET STATEMENT:  select app."LoadTraffic"()
```

I guess the *canceling statement due to user request* is the .net app canceling because timeout. Because running the stored procedure in pgAdmin didn't end neither for +100 seg. and timeout is at 70seg.

Comment: Odd issue. Can you enable checkpoint logging please? `log_checkpoint = on`. Personally I'd attach a debugger to the "orphan" backends to see what they were doing and what type of backend they are, but that's probably not within your comfort zone unless you've done a bit of development work. In case it is: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Windows

Comment: @CraigRinger i made the change for `log_checkpoint`. Do i have to turn off the service and restart to that change be active or just updating the config make it work?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza A `SELECT pg_reload_conf()` or `pg_ctl reload` is sufficient.